# What is load current and load speed? Which battery is best suitable for this motor?

Tags: motor

These are the specifications of the motor:

> 25000RPM no load speed at 12V
>
> No Load Current - 1A, Stall Current - 10A
>
> 0.36Kgcm torque

What is the definition of load current and load speed? Which battery would be most suitable to power this motor?

Comment: Hi Arshdeep, Welcome to SE! You may want to read [the tour page](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to read the information you found:

The motor you are describing will draw the least amount of current when there is no load (1A), and the most amount of current when it is stalled (10A).  Think of it this way: when the motor can't turn (being stalled), it's at its maximum load -- you can't make it turn slower than zero$^*$.

The load speed will depend on what the motor is trying to do.  As you noted, if there is no load it will be spinning at 25,000 RPM.  This can go all the way down to zero, depending on circumstances.

Whichever battery you use should be able to supply just over 10A peak current, if you want to get the maximum performance from this motor.

> $*$ In practice, you can make a motor run backwards (such as if it was spinning one way and you slammed it into reverse), and this can make it draw more than the stall current.